# Error with document.write and XML in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

```
"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Permission denied"
```

I'm getting this problem on this line:

```
_this._xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = Function.emptyMethod;
```

Basically what I'm doing is trying to loop through XML. Everything works fine, but the minute I call document.write(); it gives me this problem.

EDIT: I'm basically trying to achieve this: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_display_table

But in my code, I'm not doing this:

`xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML`;

I'm loading my XML like this instead (XML from a WCF web service):

```
xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.loadXML(result.xml);
```

Any help seriously appreciated.

EDIT: Complete code:

```
function pageLoad() {
        ClassRegistrationServices.GetClassRegistrationReport(success, failure);
    }

    function success(result) {
        document.getElementById('txtValueContainer').value = result;
        xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDom");
        xmlDoc.async = false;
        xmlDoc.loadXML(result.xml);

        var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ClassRegistrationReport_Result");

        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            testVar = x[i].getElementsByTagName("Class_Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You say document.write, BUT you do not show document.write in your code.

Comment: I will edit to include my complete javascript code...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`document#write` is a HTML specific method as far as I know. You should probably go into detail on what you try to achieve.

---

[Link to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write)

Comment: I'm trying to achieve what they have achieved on the link in my post. I'm trying to loop through an XML object I have, and write it's contents to a HTML table.

Comment: @Daniel McNulty Again, are you trying to do this in a XHTML `document`? If so, it won't work because it does not exist.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot FK82. I solved this problem anyway, but the reason as to why it never worked remained a mystery until your response - so thanks a lot.